# Local bitnami/magento docker setup

Tags: magento2, installation, docker, http-request

I am trying to set up a local instance of Magento to play around with.

I am having difficulties using this image: [bitnami/magento](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/magento/)

I am able to get the homepage up but doing anything else ends with the site can't be reached.

I wasn't even able to get the homepage before. I'm getting stuck at the homepage.

I made a docker-compose file which I got a template from bitnami:

```
version: '2'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: 'bitnami/mariadb:10.2'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - MARIADB_USER=bn_magento
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=magento_db_password
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_magento
    volumes:
      - 'mariadb_data:/bitnami'
  magento:
    image: 'bitnami/magento:2'
    environment:
      - MARIADB_HOST=mariadb
      - MARIADB_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - MAGENTO_DATABASE_USER=bn_magento
      - MAGENTO_DATABASE_PASSWORD=magento_db_password
      - MAGENTO_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_magento
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=elasticsearch
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PORT_NUMBER=9200
      - MAGENTO_HOST=localhost
      - EXTERNAL_HTTP_PORT_NUMBER=8085
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '8085:80'
    volumes:
      - 'magento_data:/bitnami'
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
      - elasticsearch
  elasticsearch:
    image: 'bitnami/elasticsearch:6'
    volumes:
      - 'elasticsearch_data:/bitnami/elasticsearch/data'
volumes:
  elasticsearch_data:
    driver: local
  mariadb_data:
    driver: local
  magento_data:
    driver: local
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento requires SSL on certian URLs.

Basically I had to follow the documentation here and edit it to my own localhost by adding:

```
MAGENTO_HOST=localhost
EXTERNAL_HTTP_PORT_NUMBER=8085
EXTERNAL_HTTPS_PORT_NUMBER=8086
```

Then I added port bindings:

```
ports:
  - '80:80'
  - '443:443'
  - '8085:80'
  - '8086:443'
```

So far everything works and Magento requires SSL on certain URLS

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to your own question, it helped me!

Comment: I do not know how to access the homepage? I tried access localhost:8085 and https://localhost:8086 but the connection faild. Can one of you please guide me? I ran the deocker compose file mentione dabove, by adding additional ports and EXTERNAL_HTTPS_PORT_NUMBER mentioned int eh answer

Comment: @Justin make a new question and tag me or link here. but be sure to add your code and config files and explain it as you go